# Concrete Mathematics (Knuth, Graham, Patashnik): Initial repertoire item for Josephus example (follow-up from 1.14)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There is a mini-induction used to bootstrap our first repertoire item ($\alpha = 1, \beta = \gamma = 0$) for the Josephus proof using a three variable repertoire. This induction step is not shown, I suspect, because it is very simple. However I want to check I understand what the induction steps actually are.

To quote the text:

> Let's illustrate this by considering the special case $\alpha = 1, \beta = \gamma = 0$, when $f(n)$ is supposed to be equal to $A(n)$: Recurrence (1.11) becomes
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> A(1) &= 1; \\
> A(2n) &= 2A(n) \\
> A(2n + 1) &= 2A(n) \\
> \end{align}
> $$
> **Sure enough, it's true (by induction on m) that $A(2^m + \ell) = 2^m$**

(Bold my own emphasis)

They don't show the induction steps for that simple case so I just want to check my understanding.

This repertoire item only covers the cases where $n$ is a power of two so $\ell$ is always $0$ I think? So we could leave it out of the induction substitution? Thus it would look like this for both the odd and even cases:

$$
\begin{align}
A(2^m + \ell) &= 2(2^{m-1}) \\
       &= 2^m
\end{align}
$$

Is this what they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible (I don't know) that you're dealing with a situation where you only need to consider the $\ell=0$ case, but this claim is true more broadly. The induction on $m$ looks like this:

When $m=0$, since $0 \le \ell < 2^m$ we have $\ell=0$ as well. Then $A(2^m+\ell) = A(1) = 1 = 2^m$, and the formula holds.

Now assume for a particular $m$ that for any $0 \le \ell < 2^m$ we have $A(2^m+\ell) = 2^m$, and consider the expression $A(2^{m+1} + \ell)$ for some $0 \le \ell < 2^{m+1}$. Then:

- If $\ell$ is even we have $A(2^{m+1}+\ell) = 2 A(2^m + \frac \ell 2)$ and since $0 \le \frac{\ell}{2} < 2^m$, by the inductive hypothesis $A(2^m + \frac \ell 2) = 2^m$, so we get $A(2^{m+1}+\ell) = 2(2^m) = 2^{m+1}$.
- If $\ell$ is odd we have $A(2^{m+1}+\ell) = 2 A(2^m + \frac{\ell-1}{2})$ and since $0 \le \frac{\ell-1}{2} < 2^m$, by the inductive hypothesis $A(2^m + \frac{\ell-1}{2}) = 2^m$, so we get $A(2^{m+1}+\ell) = 2(2^m) = 2^{m+1}$.

In both cases, we get $A(2^{m+1}+\ell) = 2^{m+1}$, proving the inductive step; therefore the desired formula holds for all $m$.